# Sort subgroups of lines in text file

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have a server property file called `filelist.txt`. This filelist contains a list of files which are arranged in groups based upon their directory prefix. The ordering of the contents is important, in that the file must start and end with specific file names, and the first subgroup must appear first. For example, the file looks like:

```
config.txt
../../linux/a.txt
../../linux/c.txt
../../linux/d.txt
../../linux/b.txt
../../certificates/../../d.txt
../../certificates/../../a.txt
../../certificates/../../c.txt
../../certificates/../..b.txt
../../bin/b.txt
../../bin/a.txt
properties.server
```

What I am wondering is what is the best way to sort within these subgroups in a clean and efficient way, while maintaining the overall ordering of the subgroups?

I wrote this code which can filter by a subgroup and sort it:

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/filelist.txt"))){

            List<String> linez = lines.filter(l -> l.contains("linux")).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/output.txt"));

            for(String line : linez){
                bw.write(line+"\n");
            }

            bw.close();
```

I could have a `List<String>` which will contain all of my lines, and I could filter the original file lines, sort them, and then add them to this list.

There's a couple things that I don't like:

1. I'm not overwriting the original file, I'm writing to a new one. I'd like to see if there is a way to overwrite instead of writing to a new file.
2. It seems a bit obtuse. What if there is a new directory prefix that gets added? Then I'll have to edit this code again to filter and sort that new directory prefix group. Also, it would feel weird making a bunch of different lists for each subgroup based on each filter, instead of doing something like `lines.filter(...).sort().filter(...).sort().filter(...)`, but I don't think that kind of syntax makes sense yet, because once the filter is applied, after the sort I can't unapply the filter. It would be really nice to be able to filter, sort in place, then apply another filter and sort, and so on.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on [Shawn’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70706616/2711488) but simplifies the operation by directly sorting the affected groups within the original list.

```java
try {
    Path datafile = Path.of(args[0]);
    var lines = Files.readAllLines(datafile);

    // ensure that the list is mutable
    if(lines.getClass() != ArrayList.class) lines = new ArrayList<>(lines);

    int first = 1; // skip first line
    int last = lines.size() - 1; // and last line

    if(first >= last) return;

    Path previous = Path.of(lines.get(first));
    for (int i = first + 1; i < last; i++) {
        Path p = Path.of(lines.get(i));
        if(!p.getParent().equals(previous.getParent())) {
            lines.subList(first, i).sort(null);
            first = i;
            previous = p;
        }
    }
    // Handle the last block of paths
    if(first < last) lines.subList(first, last).sort(null);

    // Overwrite the original input file
    Files.write(datafile, lines);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Note that the type of the list returned by `Files.lines` is unspecified, but always an `ArrayList` in practice. The solution protects itself against the hypothetical case that the returned list is not mutable, but does not perform the copying operation in real life. So it’s both, formally correct and efficient.

Comment: Isn't possible something like this? `try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/filelist.txt"))) {
            stream.skip(1)
                    .map(Path::of)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Path::getParent, LinkedHashMap::new,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), paths -> paths.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())))).values();
        }`

Comment: @HadiJ yes, that would work but require additional storage, even more than Shawn’s answer which utilizes the fact that the group items are already adjacent in the source file.

Answer (score 3):

Streams aren't the best approach (At least not for the entire job; maybe for parts of it). The following uses the approach of looking at each line, and if the path up to the last component is the same as the previously read one, adding it to a list, and if not, sorting that list of paths and then adding them to the sorted results, so that the order of each prefix group is unchanged, but each group ends up sorted.

Overwriting the input file is just a matter of using the same file for reading and writing - just make sure to read everything before opening it for writing. The below just reads the file into a list before processing it.

```java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path datafile = Path.of(args[0]);
            var lines = Files.readAllLines(datafile);
            var sorted = new ArrayDeque<String>(lines.size());

            // Add first line
            sorted.addLast(lines.get(0));

            // Iterate through all the remaining but the last line
            var block = new ArrayDeque<Path>();
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.size() - 1; i++) {
                Path p = Path.of(lines.get(i));
                if (!block.isEmpty()
                    && !p.getParent().equals(block.getLast().getParent())) {
                    // Current path has a different prefix than the current
                    // block. Sort block and add it to output
                    block.stream()
                        .sorted()
                        .forEachOrdered(sp ->
                                        sorted.addLast(sp.toString()));
                    // And reset for a new path prefix
                    block.clear();
                }
                block.addLast(p);
            }
            // Handle the last block of paths
            block.stream()
                .sorted()
                .forEachOrdered(sp -> sorted.addLast(sp.toString()));

            // Add last line
            sorted.addLast(lines.get(lines.size() - 1));

            // Overwrite the original input file
            Files.write(datafile, sorted);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see the reason to use `ArrayDeque` here. Both, adding to the end and clear, work equally well with `ArrayList`, but the latter allows to directly [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) and can [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Iterable,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) back with one statement. Well, I suppose the latter would work the a deque too.

Comment: @Holger `getLast()` is very handy.

Comment: I’m not sure whether that should drive the decision. In fact, when you just keep the last in a variable, `Path last`, you not only don’t need `getLast()`, you also don’t need to store `Path` objects in the list but can use the original `String`. Then, you can simply use `addAll` and do not need to call `toString()` on the `Path` again. You could even go one step further and get rid of the temporary deque/list and identify the group boundaries in the `lines` list and use `lines.subList(…).sort(null)` to sort a group and write back with `Files.write(datafile, lines);` without ever copying sth.

Comment: @Holger That sounds way too complicated. Certainly way too complicated for the effort i'm willing to put in for a answer.

Comment: Whether it’s too complicated might be subjective or perhaps, I wasn’t good at describing it. So it’s ok if you’re not trying it, I added the answer. Code explains better what I mean… Oh, and have my upvote for providing the basis, of course.